# Batch - Search a precise line in a file

Tags: variables, search, for-loop, batch-file

i have a long game config and i want to make an overview as a batch screen.
 What i"m trying to do, is that the batch script looks at a specified line and then picks an info.

 Ex :

> Tax Rate : 15
>   Admin Rate : 20
>   Mod Rate : 18

I'd want the script to look in line 2 after the 13 digits (`Admin Rate :`) and set the outut as a variable.
Such as

> for /f in delim=2;13 in ('config.yml') do set adminrate

So at the end i can output clearly all the configs.

> echo Admin Rate : %adminrate%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just selects the 2nd line, if that is needed.

EDITED to return the entire line.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "config.txt" ^| findstr "^\[2\]" ') do set "variable=%%b"
echo "%variable%"
pause
```

Note that if the selected line starts with ] characters then they will be removed from the string.

Comment: It would be nice if it selected the whole line ! When i use it, it only selects the first caracter ... I used this file to test it : [link](http://pastebin.com/01LizNQz) I changed the `findstr "^\[23\]"` so it would select the 23rd line, but it ended up with just the brackets `""`. any ideas ?

Comment: I've changed it to return the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /c:"Admin Rate" "config.yml"') do set "adminrate=%%a"
echo(%adminrate%
```

Comment: i'm notvery familiar with the for command but what does this do (so i can customize it ..) ?